# How to export a brochure into PDF with each layout as a page?

Tags: macos, layout, iwork-pages

I have created a 3-fold brochure in Mac iWork - Pages.

If I print the brochure then I can 3-fold it and everything is fine.

But if I want to export as PDF then I get a 2-A4 size pages, and this distorts the user the order of the pages, I would like to export each layout as a separate page.

The 'Layout Break' option is diabled and I don't know how to enable it?

Any ideas? Thanks.

[E.g 3-fold brochure](http://www.yourdesigner.com/images/services_images/Tri-Fold-Brochure2.jpg)

Comment: Can you save to pdf properly from the print dialog box? 

Is your paper size A4 in Page setup?  Do you want the final size to be A4 or letter(8.5 by 11) or something else? 

Your third paragraph is unclear... "this distorts the user the order of the pages, I would like to export each layout as a separate page."

I'm not sure what is actually means.

Comment: Added link to a 3-fold brochure...now I want to export this to a 6 page PDF document and not 2 page.

Answer (score 0):

If printing works fine for you, why not "print" to a PDF instead of exporting as PDF?

Mac OS X does this [natively](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_print_pdf_file_mac_os_x.html), so when you open your print dialog, simply pick the PDF option in the lower left and then "Save As PDF...".